# Find the derivative of the fucntion using difference quotient

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We define

### $f(x)$ = $x^{1/5}$

I applied the formula and got the following result: $f'(x)$ = $\lim_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

After plugging in the respective values, this is what I ended up with:
$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^{1/5} - x^{1/5}}{h}$

I thought that I could multiply the numerator and denominator with the conjugate of the above function but somehow I was unable to get the required derivative. Could you guys shed some insight towards this?

Comment: Hint:$$(x^s)'= (e^{s \cdot \log x})' = e^{s \cdot \log x} \cdot (s \cdot \log x)'$$

Comment: There is a simole trick here. Put $k=(x+h) ^{1/5}-x^{1/5},y=x^{1/5}$ and then $h=(y+k)^5-y^5$ so desired limit is $\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{k}{(y+k)^5-y^5}$. I hope you can now easily handle it.

Comment: Usually textbooks describe the technique I mentioned in my comment. Do check your textbook.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh could you explain why you took $h$ to be $(y+k)^5 - y^5$?

Comment: I defined $k$ as something and using that equation if you solve for $h$ you will get the desired expression.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I get it now. Thanks a lot for your assistance.

Comment: Let me know if you face any further issues with this question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh there was a slightly different expression that I took. Instead of taking $k = (x + h)^{1/5} - x^{1/5}$, I just took $k$ to be as $k = (x + h)^{1/5}$ and the $y$ was the same as the one that you used. Solved the equation after that and applied the limits to get the answer.